# Limit max velocity of a particle in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im working on a little project, I have some particles i want to move towards target positions without exceeding a max velocity, first i tried capping the X and Y velocities seperately which caused the hypotenuse of the two to be able to go over the max speed, i then remembered my maths classes and attempted this:

```
    var totalVel = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(curVelocity[0],2) + Math.pow(curVelocity[1],2));
    if(totalVel > maxSpeed){
        //sin(θ) = Opposite / Hypotenuse
        var angle = Math.asin(curVelocity[1]/totalVel);
        var newHyp = maxSpeed;

        var newOp = Math.sin(angle)*newHyp;
        var newAdj = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(newHyp,2) - Math.pow(newOp,2));

        curVelocity[1] = newOp;
        curVelocity[0] = newAdj;
    }
```

(curVelocity is an array where index 0 is X and index 1 is Y)
This works well hald the time, the other time it curves away from the target its trying to reach.. matches it on the Y plane but heads in the whole wrong direction in the X plane. im guessing its something to do with using math.sin when perhaps it no longer applies in the direction its traveling but i wouldnt know where ot begin differentiating what to use, or if that idea is even correct.

A live example of what im talking about can be found at [this location here](http://trotskihome.zapto.org/test/test.html), refreshing the page will change the starting location and target location, the black circle is the particle the green circle is the target location